# using pytest-mock mocker to mock object constructions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am trying to use pytest-mock to mock test a function which create an object:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
class A():
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        print('A', a)

def my_fun(a: int):
    return A(a)

def test_me(mocker):
    mocker.patch(f'{__name__}.A.__new__', new_callable=lambda: MagicMock(spec_set=A))
    o1 = my_fun(1)
    print('o1', o1)
    o2 = my_fun(2)
    print('o2', o2)
```

The output is:

```
o1 <MagicMock name='mock()' id='140737208963280'>
o2 <MagicMock name='mock()' id='140737208963280'>
```

I would expect that o1 and o2 hold 2 different MagicMock objects, but looks like I got the same one. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem now. The code should be:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
class A():
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        print('A', a)

def my_fun(a: int):
    return A(a)

def test_me(mocker):
    mocker.patch(f'{__name__}.A.__new__', side_effect=lambda *args, **kwargs: MagicMock(spec_set=A))
    o1 = my_fun(1)
    print('o1', o1)
    o2 = my_fun(2)
    print('o2', o2)
```

output:

```
o1 <MagicMock spec_set='A' id='140737208906384'>
o2 <MagicMock spec_set='A' id='140737209072976'>
```